# MetaMask Ether Faucet

Tags: javascript, ethereum, metamask

Please anyone can tell what should I do? I get this error:

```
Error: 500 {"error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"Too Many Requests\",\"data\":{\"originalError\":{}},\"stack\":\"Error: Too Many Requests\\n at eval (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:52:23)\\n at Request.eval [as _callback] (/www/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc.js:54:11)\\n at Request.self.callback (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)\\n at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\\n at Request.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1155:10)\\n at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)\\n at IncomingMessage.eval (/www/node_modules/request/request.js:1077:12)\\n at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)\\n at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)\\n at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)\"}}'"}
```

Comment: Answering this would involve knowing *something* about the code & circumstances that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have sent too many requests in a short period of time as it hints in the response property called message `"message": "Too Many Requests"`. Now rate limits cooldown time differs for every service out there, but you can try to wait for a couple of minutes and try again, if you still receive you might have to wait for an hour, a day and so on.